# Scipy fsolve: No solution invalidates all valid solutions

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to back out Black-Scholes implied volatilities from financial options data. If the data contains options for which an implied volatility cannot be found, this will make all the results equal to the initial guess. See the following example

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

S = 1293.77
r = 0.05
K = np.array([1255, 1260, 1265, 1270, 1275])
T = 2./365
price = np.array([38.9, 34.35, 29.7, 25.35, 21.05])

def black_scholes(S, K, r, T, sigma):
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + sigma ** 2 / 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(T)
    return S * norm.cdf(d1) - K * np.exp(-r * T) * norm.cdf(d2)

volatility = lambda x: black_scholes(S, K, r, T, x) - price

print fsolve(volatility, np.repeat(0.1, len(K)))
```

gives

```
RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
[ 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]
```

By doing the same operation with Matlab or Maple I know that no solution can be found for the first option. If I exclude that one, such that

```
K = np.array([1260, 1265, 1270, 1275])
price = np.array([34.35, 29.7, 25.35, 21.05])
```

I do get the right result

```
[ 0.19557092  0.20618568  0.2174149   0.21533821]
```

Therefore if a solution cannot be found I would expect `fsolve` to return `NaN` instead of my initial guess and not mess up the rest of the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `full_output` argument to tell [`fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) to return more information, and check the value of `ier` on return.  For example,

```
sol, info, ier, msg = fsolve(volatility, np.repeat(0.1, len(K)), full_output=True)

if ier != 1:
    print "ier = %d" % (ier,)
    print msg
else:
    print "sol =", sol
```

You said:

> ...if a solution cannot be found I would expect fsolve to return NaN instead of my initial guess and not mess up the rest of the solutions.

`fsolve` has no way of knowing that the problem you are solving is actually a collection of decoupled problems.  You've given it a single n-dimensional problem.  Either it succeeds or it fails to find a solution to that problem.